# How to plot constant vertical lines where x is a constant in Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

How can I plot the set of constant vertical line x=0,1,2,3.. in Mathematica?

When I set Plot[1, {x, 0, 5}] then it is a horizontal line which means it sets y=1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
p={{{1,0},{1,3}},{{2,0},{2,3}},{{3,0},{3,3}}};
ListPlot[p,Joined->True]
```

If you need to then you can adjust the coloring and other graphics options like any other Plot.